# Why does my function produces a Conflicting Types error?

Tags: c, function, gcc, compiler-errors, function-declaration

I tried to reproduce the function atof() from the C language book without looking at it, i wrote it and every line of code seemed to be right, but when I compile the program it tells me that there is a conflicting type error .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

float atof(char s[]); // the error is produced here

int main()
{
    char line[100] = "672";
    float num = atof(line);

    printf("%f", num);
    return 0;
}

// I didn't finish the function yet...
float atof(char s[])
{
    int i, sign;
    float n;
    for(i = 0; s[i] == ' '; i++)  // skip white spaces
        ;
    // set sign to the -1 if it is negative, 1 if else
    sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if(s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-')
        i++;
    for(n = 0.0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
    {
        n = 10.0 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    }
    return n * sign;
}
```

**What I tried :**

- I thought that the problem occurred because this function already exists in one of the libraries that I included, so I changed it name to strtof() and the problem was the same .
- I tried to change the type of the function instead but the problem was still there .
- I tried to return a float `return 2.5F` and double `return 2.5` but that didn't solve the issue .

( btw I use gcc compiler version 9.2.0 )

Comment: Since [the `atof` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atof) already is declared in one specific way in the `<stdlib.h>` header, and you declare it again in a way not compatible with the standard function, you get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I thought that the problem occurred because this function already exists in one of the libraries that I included, so I changed it name to `strtof()` and the problem was the same .*

You are almost there: `strtof()` and `atof()` are both library functions for your platform. use something like `my_strtof()` or `my_atof()`.

Reference:

- [man `strtof()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof) - prototyped in `stdlib.h`
- [man `atof()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atof) - prototyped in `stdlib.h`

and both are standard C library functions.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard already contains a function with the name `atof` in the header `<stdlib.h>`.

It is declared like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
double atof(const char *nptr);
```

So your function declaration conflicts with the C standard function declaration with the same name.

You need to rename your function.

And declare the parameter with the qualifier `const` the same way as the parameter of the standard function is declared.

Also pay attention that there is a typo in your function.

Instead of the assignment in this statement

```
sign = (s[i] = '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

there shall be comparison

```
sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: Haha yeah I've seen this small error, I just didn't look at the function when I asked this question because I was worried about the error, thanks' for the help